Uninformative prior on variance parameter of spatial effect in Gibbs sampler to enhance convergence
I am trying to fit the Bayesian finite mixture model presented in Allen et al. (2023). This model uses a multivariate CAR effect in modelling the linear predictor of the outcome. In addition the mixture weights, individual to each sample, are modeled using a multinomial logistic regression model. Limiting ourselves to this sub-model, it is given by this:
$$
\pi_{ig} = \frac{exp(\boldsymbol{w}_i^T \boldsymbol{\rho}_g + \psi_{ig})}{\sum_{h=1}^G exp(\boldsymbol{w}_i^T \boldsymbol{\rho}_h + \psi_{ih})}
$$
where $g = 1, \cdots, G$ are the mixture components, $\boldsymbol{w}_i$ is a length $p$ vector of covariates, $\boldsymbol{\rho}_g$ is a length $p$ vector of fixed effects, and $\psi_{ig}$ is a spatial random effect known as a univariate IAR effect. Latter is also known alternatively as the Besag model. This IAR effect is given by the following expression:
$$
\psi_{ig} \mid \psi_{-ig}, \nu_g^2 \sim \mathcal{N}\Big( \frac{1}{m_i} \sum_{l \in \delta_i} \psi_{lg}, \frac{\nu_g^2}{m_i} \Big)
$$
To derive closed-form full conditional distributions for a Gibbs sampler, Polya-Gamma data augmentation is used. Please see the paper in the above hyperlink in case you are unfamiliar with this.
Now I run a Gibbs sampler also derived by Allen et al. (2023) for this specific multinomial logistic regression. I isolated only this sub-model to troubleshoot the following problem. Namely, the variance parameter, $\nu_g^2$, does not appear to converge to the true underlying value. The updating rule in the code for this specific is given by the following:
Nu2[k] <- 1/rgamma(1,.01 + (n-1)/2,.01 + (t(PSI[,k]) %*% Q %*% PSI[,k])/2)

Hence we see that the $\alpha$ parameter is fixed based on the sample size, $n$, but the $\beta$ parameter is allowed to vary depending on the size of the spatial effects, $\boldsymbol{\phi}$, in the specific iteration. In addition it appears that an inverse-Gamma prior is used that is conjugate with the normally distributed spatial effect. Explicitly given by $IG(0.01, 0.01)$.
Whenever I run this Gibbs sampler on simulated data, the true underlying parameter is not recovered. Instead it appears to set all PSI-values to zero in only a handful of iterations. Hence we get  estimates that are approximately drawn from:
1/rgamma(1, 0.01 + (n-1)/2, 0.01 + 0)

I tried reading some papers by Andrew Gelman, who appears to suggest the $IG(\epsilon, \epsilon)$ priors aren't truly uninformative, but push the posterior distribution of $\nu_g^2$ to zero. This same thing appears to be happening here.
My questions are the following: Do you think my diagnosis of the problem is correct, namely that the hyperprior is pushing the estimates to zero? How can I remedy this? Gelman suggests parameter expansions, but gives examples I am unable to generalize to my exact situation. Are there any other priors that might be more suitable than the inverse-Gamma? And any ideas on how to implement this code-wise?
